# Export to xml from VB

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net

I've the following code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles     Button1.Click
        Dim cnn As New SqlConnection("Server=test;uid=sa;pwd=1234;database=empatic")
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from producte for xml path('producte'), root('Productes')", cnn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        Dim a As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
        Dim x = XDocument.Parse(a)
        Dim s = x.ToString()
        TextBoxXml.Text = s
    End Sub
End Class
```

What does this code display the contents of the SQL text in a Frame. What I would like now is to create another button then click when I generate an XML file with the contents listed in the Frame text.

Comment: Your question is confusing, can you try to rewrite it to be more clear.

Comment: Hello, I can't find the way to be more clear.

Comment: Either use a XML library to write that or do some stupid string concatenation your own. This is not a real programming question.

Comment: Sorry, I'll think more my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\temp\someXml.xml", TextBoxXml.Text)`

Comment: Hi @paul, Now I've seen that I think I'm missing something about the xml document, xml header. How do I make it appear?

Comment: The xml declaration is not stored in SQL server, so you'll have to add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>` at the beginning of all your results.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance @paul, but how do I do that?

Comment: `Dim xmlWithDeclaration As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1"" ?>" + TextBoxXml.Text`

Comment: Hi @paul , How can I do a end of line between the xml header and the code.

Comment: `Dim xmlWithDeclaration As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1"" ?>" + Environment.NewLine + TextBoxXml.Text`